# How to issue a wrapped token to an existing ERC-20 token?

Tags: erc-20, wrapped-tokens

I have already issued an ERC-20 token with a fixed supply amount. How can I issue a Wrapped token?

Comment: What do you mean by "wrapped token"? What's the purpose?

Comment: Check this tutorial https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/erc20-wrapper-tutorial/23536?u=julissadantes disclaimer: I wrote it